# If we're linking out, we ought to prioritize our own answers over of external resources

Tags: discussion

As a Q&A site, we naturally link to a lot of external URLs. Part of what makes q&a sites awesome is that we typically link to the *right* pages.

Before linking out, I encourage everyone to look inward first...we have *a lot* of amazing answers that fall through the cracks. I'm not just up here trying to be a goody two shoes either. I link out all the time.

But after looking at a few things I strongly believe that cannibalization + internal link architecture issues are inhibiting our site quite a bit when it comes to organic search.

*We* ought to have that sort of thing on lock, yeah?

Just a thought.

I have absolutely, positively, no data to support my theory...but my gut says it's true. I welcome any and all criticism/speculation. Let's think it out. But there's *sure* as heck something wacky going on with the site.

Comment: Agreed that we have a lot of great answers here, ripe for internal links. One thing I do a lot that I find mondo helpful is to type into Google search `site:webmasters.stackexchange.com the topic I am looking for`. More often than not, it returns a post that I can internal link for context, and it does so more efficiently than Stack Exchange's built in search. As a side note it's also great for finding duplicate questions, when a question comes in that you're just *sure* has been asked before.

Comment: Also, more specifically what kind of wackiness are you seeing? At a glance Webmaster SE's Google presence seems about what I would expect, but it sounds like you're looking at it in greater detail than me!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Spectacular comments above. Re: wackiness - It's likely that we're looking at different things, rather than one in more detail than another. Too tired to do more type. Let's discuss manana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three good places to look for pages on our site that have great content to link to:

- [Questions ranked by number of votes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes)
- [Frequent questions (by # of duplicates)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Frequent)
- [Questions with 50,000+ views](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A50000)

Here are the 37 questions that I have bookmarked to use as reference links:

- [Are drops in Google ranking common after switching to https?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103607/are-drops-in-google-ranking-common-after-switching-to-https)
- [Are keywords in URLs good SEO or needlessly redundant?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant)
- [Canonical URL for a home page and trailing slashes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31796/canonical-url-for-a-home-page-and-trailing-slashes)
- [How to avoid SSL warnings about certificate not for the current site when redirecting alternate domains?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113180/how-to-avoid-ssl-warnings-about-certificate-not-for-the-current-site-when-redire/113181)
- [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)
- [Does a site's bounce rate influence Google rankings?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13920/does-a-sites-bounce-rate-influence-google-rankings)
- [Does changing web hosting affect search engine rankings?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/does-changing-web-hosting-affect-search-engine-rankings)
- [Does the order of keywords matter in a page title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title)
- [Google doesn't seem to update the description or title of my homepage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8710/google-doesnt-seem-to-update-the-description-or-title-of-my-homepage)
- [How bad is it to use display: none in CSS?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)
- [How can I prevent my mail from being classified as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam)
- [How does "Noindex:" in robots.txt work?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84884/how-does-noindex-in-robots-txt-work)
- [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)
- [How to avoid SSL warnings about certificate not for the current site when redirecting alternate domains?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113180/how-to-avoid-ssl-warnings-about-certificate-not-for-the-current-site-when-redire)
- [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)
- [How to fight off Google Analytics referrer spammers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-google-analytics-referrer-spammers)
- [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)
- [HTTP to HTTPS: Wait for new sitemap to be indexed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110067/http-to-https-wait-for-new-sitemap-to-be-indexed)
- [Huge drop [50%] in traffic after HTTPS move](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78820/huge-drop-50-in-traffic-after-https-move)
- [If ICANN only charges 18¢ per domain name, why am I paying $10?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61467/if-icann-only-charges-18-per-domain-name-why-am-i-paying-10)
- [Is word count a large ranking factor for Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/is-word-count-a-large-ranking-factor-for-google)
- [Prevent XML sitemaps from showing up in Google search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/prevent-xml-sitemaps-from-showing-up-in-google-search-results)
- [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)
- [SEO preference: does a site with WWW rank better than without WWW?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11560/seo-preference-does-a-site-with-www-rank-better-than-without-www)
- [Should I include "www" in my website's URLs? What are the pros and cons?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/507/should-i-include-www-in-my-websites-urls-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)
- [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)
- [Title tag different from title appearing in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google)
- [URLs: Should I use hyphens, underscores or plus symbols?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/374/urls-should-i-use-hyphens-underscores-or-plus-symbols)
- [Using multiple A-records for my domain - do web browsers ever try more than one?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/using-multiple-a-records-for-my-domain-do-web-browsers-ever-try-more-than-one)
- [Well structured URLs vs. URLs optimized for SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo)
- [What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)
- [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)
- [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)
- [What is the best placement for the ID in a URL for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16641/what-is-the-best-placement-for-the-id-in-a-url-for-seo)
- [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)
- [Why do Alexa rankings for a site fluctuate by millions day to day?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/why-do-alexa-rankings-for-a-site-fluctuate-by-millions-day-to-day)
- [Why do Google search results include pages disallowed in robots.txt?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/why-do-google-search-results-include-pages-disallowed-in-robots-txt)

It also occurs to me that we might want to try to ask some basic questions ourselves and provide high quality answers so that we can use them as reference.   Right now I would probably look externally for a resource to link for further reading on these subjects:

- What is search engine optimization (SEO)?
- What is a canonical tag?
- What is a redirect?
- What is a hreflang?
- What is a rewrite rule?
- What is .htaccess?
- What is shared hosting?
- What is a dedicated server?
- What is cloud hosting?
- What is DNS?
- What is a CNAME?
- What is an A record?

Comment: This is a great resource Stephen. Thank you for providing this. I absolutely agree that we should work on asking some basic/general questions of our own and providing HQ answers - fantastic idea. We could even provide an "FAQ" section internally linking to top questions on the subject. This also helps us more easily deal with duplicates, as we'll have general content to direct broad/vague questions. Should we create an initiative on a separate question?

Comment: A separate question for an initiative would be good I think.  Can you spearhead that?

Comment: I'd be happy to. Just put one up for the broken links project too.